# how to prevent coordinator listen itself

Tags: python, xbee

I have a xbee coordinator. I have broadcast message to the other xbees but coordiator gets its message and sends acknowledges to itself. How can I stop xbee coordinator which is configured as broadcaster to listen itself ?

Answer (score 0):

When using an XBee module in API mode, the headers of each frame will indicate which device sent the message.  You could look at the sender's address, and if it matches the local device then you ignore the message.

You might want to look at using the [python-xbee](http://code.google.com/p/python-xbee/) library in your project, as it will make it easy to use the XBee module's API mode for sending and receiving.